# How to excute this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I have flash games website that allows users to "like" or "dislike" a particular game. When the user selects "like/dislike", my php application inserts a record into a table named `likes` which contains the following columns:

- `game_id` - (ID of the selected game)
- `time` - (the time of the user action, per the time function in php)
- `type` - (the action type: "like" or "dislike")

How should I fetch the id's of 10 games having the most "likes" ie `type ='like'`, in the last week ie `week(time()-60*60*24*7)`. Then order the results by the greatest number of "likes" per game?

Here is the query I tried using, but it's still not helping. As it only fetches all of the `like` records, not the totals.

```
    SELECT `game_id` 
    FROM   `likes` 
    WHERE  `type` = 'like' 
    AND    `time` > '{$time}'
```

Comment: we could help you better if you have tried something.

Comment: I added, please check the post now. thanks

Comment: mysql? oracle? db2? mssql?

Comment: from the tag - it says sql

Comment: What column type is the time column.

Comment: Guys, the anwsers you gave here it's will fetch many times the same `game_id`, i need to fetch 10 unique `game_id` order by `type`='like' and where `time` > $time ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time column is a date column you could do this.

```
  $time = date("Y-m-d", time() - (60*60*24*7));
```

or more concisely

```
  $time = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("one week ago"));
```

and the query should read

```
  SELECT `game_id`, count(*) as num_likes 
  FROM   `likes` 
  WHERE  `type` = 'like' 
  AND    `time` > '{$time}' 
  GROUP BY game_id 
  ORDER BY num_likes desc 
  LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Actually I'm using time, no date. but that it no the problem dude. I need to get 10 `games_id` that have the most likes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Php
$time =  date_sub(now() ,interval 7 day); // Week
// SQL
SELECT `game_id` FROM `likes` WHERE `type` = 'like' AND `time` > '{$time}' LIMIT 10
```

You may need to play around with date_sub to get it just right, but hopefully this will get you on the right track.  The LIMIT 10 will limit it to 10 results, which may be all you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("one week ago"); 

$sql ="SELECT game_id, 
       COUNT(type) as like_count 
       FROM likes 
       WHERE type = 'like' AND `time` > ".$timestamp." 
       GROUP BY type 
       ORDER BY like_count DESC
       LIMIT 0,10";
```

Comment: I tried it. id 1 have 1 like, and id 2 have 1 like, it's fetch me that id 1 have 2 likes(and id 2 not fetched). How to fix it ?

Comment: should be `ORDER BY like_count DESC`