# How to use this sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I have flash games website, and when you give like/dislike to any game it's inserting into `likes` table.

Here are the columns of `likes` table:

1. `game_id` (the game id you gave like)
2. `time` (the time you gave like by time function in php)
3. `type` (the like type-like/dislike).

How should I fetch 10 games id that have the most likes(`type='like'`) in the last week(`time()-60*60*24*7`) and order by the most likes per game?

The query I thought about right now, but it's still not helping only fetch all likes rows.

```
// Php
$time = time() - 60*60*24*7 // Week
// SQL
SELECT `game_id` FROM `likes` WHERE `type` = 'like' AND `time` > '{$time}'
```

Comment: This question looks very familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720534/how-to-excute-this-sql-query